# How to fix "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'" for <span>

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying a web scraper with Python 3.7 and BeautifulSoup. I've extracted data for "posting-name", "sort-by-location posting-category small-category-label", "sort-by-team posting-category small-category-label" from the following html, but can't extract "sort-by-commitment posting-category small-category-label" (either full-time or not) while the html structure seems the same as others:

```
<div class="posting" data-qa-posting-id="13f9db2f-7a80-4b50-9a61-005ad322ea2d">
   <div class="posting-apply" data-qa="btn-apply">
      <a href="https://jobs.lever.co/twitch/13f9db2f-7a80-4b50-9a61-005ad322ea2d" class="posting-btn-submit template-btn-submit hex-color">Apply</a>
   </div>
   <a class="posting-title" href="https://jobs.lever.co/twitch/13f9db2f-7a80-4b50-9a61-005ad322ea2d">
      <h5 data-qa="posting-name">Account Director - DACH</h5>
      <div class="posting-categories">
         <span href="#" class="sort-by-location posting-category small-category-label">Hamburg, Germany</span>
         <span href="#" class="sort-by-team posting-category small-category-label">Business Operations &amp; Go-To-Market – Advertising</span>
         <span href="#" class="sort-by-commitment posting-category small-category-label">Full-time</span>
      </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

I've tried creating a separate soup for "posting-categories" but didn't work.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

response = requests.get('https://jobs.lever.co/twitch')

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

posts = soup.findAll('div', {'class':'posting'})

with open('twitch.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = writer(csv_file)

    headers = ['Position', 'Link', 'Location', 'Team', 'Commitment']

    csv_writer.writerow(headers)

    for post in posts:
        position = post.find('h5',{'data-qa':'posting-name'}).text
        link = post.find('a')['href']
        location = post.find('span',{'class':'sort-by-location posting-category small-category-label'}).text
        team = post.find('span',{'class':'sort-by-team posting-category small-category-label'}).text
        commitment = post.find('span',{'class':'sort-by-commitment posting-category small-category-label'}).text
        csv_writer.writerow([position, link, location, team, commitment])
```

The expected result in csv will return the position title, link(url), location, team, and commitment.

I'm getting a following error as of now:

```
 commitment = post.find('span',{'class':'sort-by-commitment posting-category small-category-label'}).text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

*Edit: the dataset is missing this one last row, and I can't figure out why:

```
<a class="posting-title" href="https://jobs.lever.co/twitch/c8cc56e7-75f6-4cac-9983-e0769db9dd2e">
   <h5 data-qa="posting-name">Applied Scientist Intern</h5>
   <div class="posting-categories">
      <span href="#" class="sort-by-location posting-category small-category-label">San Francisco, CA</span>
      <span href="#" class="sort-by-team posting-category small-category-label">University (Internships) – Engineering</span>
      <span href="#" class="sort-by-commitment posting-category small-category-label">Intern</span>
```

Comment: `commitment = category.find(` are you supposed to use `post.find` instead? Your error and the code doesnt match.

Comment: it looks like `commitment = post.find('span',{'class':'sort-by-commitment posting-category small-category-label'}).text` raise an error because couldn't find any text during the 'find'

Comment: Your example html does not have a `div` tag of class `'posting'` so `posts = soup.findAll('div', {'class':'posting'})` produces an empty list.  Please provide an [mcve].

Comment: @abdusco Thank you for pointing that out. That was an error message from one of my iterations in trying to solve the problem. I've fixed it in the body.

Comment: @wwii I've fixed the example HTML now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the html there is some cases where `commitment` is missing in that case you have to provide if condition.Try the below code now.

```
for post in posts:
        position = post.find('h5',{'data-qa':'posting-name'}).text
        link = post.find('a')['href']
        location = post.find('span',{'class':'sort-by-location posting-category small-category-label'}).text
        team = post.find('span',{'class':'sort-by-team posting-category small-category-label'}).text
        if post.find('span',{'class':'sort-by-commitment posting-category small-category-label'}):
            commitment = post.find('span',{'class':'sort-by-commitment posting-category small-category-label'}).text
            csv_writer.writerow([position, link, location, team, commitment])
```

I would rather suggest you to use `css selector` instead of `find`.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from csv import writer

response = requests.get('https://jobs.lever.co/twitch')
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
posts = soup.select('div.posting')

with open('twitch.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
    csv_writer = writer(csv_file)

    headers = ['Position', 'Link', 'Location', 'Team', 'Commitment']

    csv_writer.writerow(headers)


    for post in posts:
        position = post.select_one('h5[data-qa="posting-name"]').text
        link = post.select_one('a')['href']
        location = post.select_one('.sort-by-location').text
        team = post.select_one('.sort-by-team').text
        if post.select_one('.sort-by-commitment'):
         commitment = post.select_one('.sort-by-commitment').text
        csv_writer.writerow([position, link, location, team, commitment])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `try except`:

```
for post in posts:
    try:
        position = post.find('h5',{'data-qa':'posting-name'}).text
        link = post.find('a')['href']
        location = post.find('span',{'class':'sort-by-location posting-category small-category-label'}).text
        team = post.find('span',{'class':'sort-by-team posting-category small-category-label'}).text
        commitment = post.find('span',{'class':'sort-by-commitment posting-category small-category-label'}).text
        csv_writer.writerow([position, link, location, team, commitment])
    except:
        continue
```